# how do I download the newest version of Haskell in a Linux virtual machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, haskell, virtual-machine, ghc

I am trying to download the newest version of Haskell on a Linux virtual machine using this command:

curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh

But this mistake pops out:

Build failed with NonZeroExit 1 "./configure" ["--prefix=/home/asepulvede/.ghcup/ghc/8.10.4"]
Check the logs at "/home/asepulvede/.ghcup/logs" and the build directory "/tmp/ghcup-gjOIJF" for more clues.

Comment: And what do the logs it's telling you to look at say?

Answer (score 1):

Generally the easiest way to get at a reliably working Haskell toolchain is to install Stack. Haskell Tool Stack is a program for developing Haskell projects. It is aimed at both new and experienced Haskel developers.
It features:

- Installing GHC automatically.
- Installing packages needed for your project.
- Building your project.
- Testing your project.
- Benchmarking your project.

To install it in Ubuntu run:

```
sudo apt install haskell-stack
```

Then you can use `stack init` / `stack setup` / `stack build` to compile your Haskell projects. See [the manual](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/).